# What is the following supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the value of the following:

$$\large \sup_{p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\min(pr+qs, qr - ps)}{\max(pr -qs, ps + qr)}$$

Edit:  By letting $a = q/p, b = s/r$, the expression simplifies to finding:

$$\large \sup_{a,b \in \mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\min(1+ab, a-b)}{\max(1-ab, a+b)}$$